# How to add rectangle into a jscrollpane with a structure in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, jscrollpane

I'm trying to do a simple slide show program in java, and as you see in the image: [image]

I want to add small rectangle's, which shows the slides like a powerpoint to a left side.

In left side, there is a `JScrollPane` but I don't know how should I add a thumbnail which shows slide's contents.

How should I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: *"I don't know how should I add a thumbnail which shows slide's contents."*  Which part are you stuck with?  Showing an image?  Arranging the images in the scrollpane?  BTW - that screen shot added nothing but bytes to the post.  It did not provide any useful information.

Comment: I dont know how should I create and images which is the same but smaller size of the big screen, and add this images into jscrollpane properly

Comment: Please see edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create ImageIcons of your images. You could show them in a JList in a JScrollPane or in a JPanel that uses GridLayout and that holds JLabels that hold the icons, again all in a JScrollPane. Myself, I much favor the JList solution as it makes it much easier to be able to select an image on mouse click.

As usual for this type of Swing GUI issue, the Swing tutorials should show you how to do all these things.

Edit: your comment to Andrew Thompson is a completely different issue and should have been mentioned in your original post. For more on that, please check out this article: [perils-of-image-getscaledinstance](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)